# Handlebars precompiled templates cannot be imported

Tags: handlebars.js

I precompile templates with the command:

```
handlebars -m -e html ./templates/ > ./templates/templates.js
```

Then I try to import the resulting file in my javascript:

```
import './templates/templates.js';
```

Which throws an error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Handlebars is not defined
```

This error appears with either full or run-time only Handlebars included. I use Handlebars 4.0.5 and bundle a project with Webpack.
Can you help with this please?

Answer (score 1):

Your precompiled templates contain a reference to the global `Handlebars` object. If you open the file, you'll see:

`(function() {
  var template = Handlebars.template,`

There's a `-c` flag to compile using CommonJS, so with

`handlebars templates.hbs -f templates-compiled.js -c handlebars/handlebars.runtime`

You'd get this in the compiled file:

`var Handlebars = require("handlebars/handlebars.runtime");`

but I'm not sure how webpack will deal with importing that.